# why wont this return false with the given array

Tags: java, recursion, return, boolean-logic

```
int[] array2 = new int[]{1,2,6,6,3,1,};
//method checks if the given array contents remain the same when array is reversed
public static boolean verify(int[] array, int index) {//method takes array and an index number

    if ((array[index] == array[array.length - index-1]) && (index < array.length/2)) {
        System.out.print("true/");
        verify(array, ++index);// increase index number to check the next values in the th array
        return true;
    } else
        System.out.println("..false..");
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: First if do `return verify(array, ++index)`

Comment: @azro this alone will not suffice. It will always return `false` with this change.

Comment: After as arzo said, add a condition for base case like `if(index >= array.length/2) return true;` also in start of function

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to say `array.length - (index - 1)`?

Comment: add also index you are passing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
public static boolean verify(int[] array, int index) {

    if (array[index] == array[array.length - index-1]) {
        if(index < array.length/2)
            return verify(array, ++index);
        return true;
    } else {...}
    return false;
}
```

You need to make sure the child value gets propagated to parent, and also check the index differently: It's not wrong, if the index is over a half of the array's length, you just don't want to check the values for such index.

Comment: It seems that there nothing in the else, apart from the print in fact

Answer (score 0):

It's best to not print the result in the method but to just print the return value.

```
public static boolean verify(int[] array, int index) {
    // don't go passed the middle
    if (index >= array.length/2) {
        return true;
    }
    // return as soon as a false comparison is found
    if(array[index] != array[array.length-index-1]) {
        return false;
    }
    // Try the next value
    return verify(array, index + 1);
}

System.out.println(verify(new int[] {1,2,3,3,3,2,1}, 0));
System.out.println(verify(new int[] {1,2,3,3,2,1}, 0));
System.out.println(verify(new int[] {1,2,4,3,3,2,1}, 0));
System.out.println(verify(new int[] {1,2,4,3,3,4,2,1}, 0));
System.out.println(verify(new int[] {1}, 0));
System.out.println(verify(new int[] {1,2}, 0));
```

Prints

```
true
true
false
true
true
false
```